# How to get the selected text or the inner html in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-html

How to get the text or the inner html of the current selection by using dart:html? I use on-mouseup event of the div as the start point to do it:

```html
<div on-mouseup="{{on_mouseup}}">
```

```js
void on_mouseup(MouseEvent e, var detail, DivElement src) {
  final selection = window.getSelection();
  // do somthing 
  // ..
  // final selectedText = ..;

  window.alert("Selected text is $selectedText!");
}
```

Example:

[image]

The value of the variable `selectedText` should be '*window.getSel*'

Comment: Your event handler argument list seems a bit weird. The passed arguments are `event`, `detail` (same as `event.detail`)*, and `target` (same as `event.target`)*. (* - the same if no dart-js-interop is involved like when  core-elements or paper-elements are used)

Comment: querySelector() is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
src.innerHtml` or `src.text
```

```dart
print(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().innerHtml);
print(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().text);
```

There is also a `shadowRoot.getSelection()` in `PolymerElement`.

```dart
print(shadowRoot.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().innerHtml);
print(shadowRoot.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().text);
```

I tried it with content outside the custom element, in the shadow DOM of the element and as child of the custom Element.

There are some issues what can be selected when the selection crosses the shadow boundary (immediately selects the entire content of the shadow DOM. Beside from that `document.getSelection()` and `shadowRoot.getSelection()` always return the same result.

It seems `getSelection` doesn't work when the end (mouse-up) is within the shadow DOM. When the selection starts in the shadow DOM and ends in the (child) content it works but not the other way around.

I think this is a bug.

Comment: I would get the only selected text. Please take a look at the updated question above.

Comment: I forgot the braces `()`. Try `window.getSelection().toString()` if the code in my answer doesn't work.

Comment: it returns "instance of 'Selection'" string.

Comment: I see. I'll have a look.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. both window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().innerHtml and window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents().text return empty string..

Comment: Maybe it's because it is inside a Polymer element. I just tried it on a Dart HTML page without polymer. I'll try it with polymer.

Comment: Yes, the div is inside the Polymer element. It seems a bug of Polymer.dart?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am going to create a new issue on https://code.google.com/p/dart.

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer might be fit better but the Dart team will move the issue over there anyway if they think it is a Polymer and not a Dart issue.