# Flutter_web detect mouse hover and click in HtmlElementView

Tags: flutter-web

I am using flutter web to parse some website.
I need to detect the mouse hover and click inside a htmlElementView and then get the corresponded element. I tried to listen the onMouseUp() but it didn't work. can you give me advise?

```
Widget myfunc(){
      ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
          'my-html',
            (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
          ..style.border = 'none'
          ..srcdoc = webData
          ..onMouseUp.listen((event) {
            print('onMouseUp => $event');
          })
          ..onSelect.listen((event) {
            print('onSelect => $event');
          })
          ..onMouseDown.listen((event) {
            print('onMouseDown=> $event');
          })
          ..onMouseEnter.listen((event) {
            print('onMouseEnter => $event');
          })
      );

return HtmlElementView(
          viewType:'my-html',
        );
}
```

I plan to follow this post to extract the element, but it only work outside of htmlElementView().
[How to get the selected text or the inner html in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926555/how-to-get-the-selected-text-or-the-inner-html-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

I don't find what is wrong but I use followed solution as an alternate.

I insert the JavaScript and listen to postMessage() on Dart side.

Step 1. add postMessage() in the HTML. I parse entire web HTML and insert the event.

```
var newElement = html.Element.html(element.outerHtml);
      print('newElement=> ${newElement.outerHtml}');
      newElement.attributes['onmouseover'] = 'window.parent.postMessage(this.id, \'*\')';
```

Step 2. Add the listener on the Dart side.

```
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    html.window.onMessage.listen( listen);
  }
  void listen(dynamic event) {
    print('listen...');
    var data = (event as html.MessageEvent).data;
    print(data);
  }
```